# Best way not to have to copy a Mat in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have this code that basically does a "dumb" background subtraction on two frames.

```
void FrameDifferenceBGS::operator()(cv::InputArray _image, cv::OutputArray _fgmask, double learningRate)
{
  cv::Mat img_input = _image.getMat();

  if(img_input.empty())
    return;

  _fgmask.create(img_input.size(), CV_8U);
  cv::Mat img_foreground = _fgmask.getMat();

  if(img_input_prev.empty())
  {
    img_input.copyTo(img_input_prev);
    return;
  }

  cv::absdiff(img_input_prev, img_input, img_foreground);

  if(img_foreground.channels() == 3)
    cv::cvtColor(img_foreground, img_foreground, CV_BGR2GRAY);

  if(enableThreshold)
    cv::threshold(img_foreground, img_foreground, threshold, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

  if(showOutput)
    cv::imshow("Frame Difference", img_foreground);

  img_input.copyTo(img_input_prev);
  img_foreground.copyTo(_fgmask);
  firstTime = false;
}
```

If I don't add `img_foreground.copyTo(_fgmask)` in the end, the output array isn't updated with the result of `img_foreground`, resulting on a black image when this is called.

What am I doing wrong / should be doing here?

Comment: Did you allocate memory for the actual parameter of `_fgmask` on the caller side?

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed your code again. It looks like you are creating new object for _fgmask.

```
 _fgmask.create(img_input.size(), CV_8U);
```

I think this is why you have the problem. Because of this reference in the argument is different from the one after this statement. Why don't you call the line before calling the function.

Comment: `_fgmask` is not a member of the class, just the argument. Also, adding the ampersands didn't fix it :-(

I'm thinking this is more to do with something obscure that OpenCV does internally than C++ constructs by themselves.

Comment: OpenCV's structures are supposed to be passed by value, they are all either light-weight structs (like cv::Vec) or headers to dynamic memory (like cv::Mat). So the original prototype is good.

Comment: @changelog In that case, I think arguments are already referenced. I reviewed your code again and updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

fix

- change   `_fgmask.create(img_input.size(), CV_8U);` to  `_fgmask.create(img_input.size(), CV_8UC3);` or  `_fgmask.create(img_input.size(), img_input.type());`

why

- this is because `cv::absdiff(img_input_prev, img_input, img_foreground);` recreate a new array everytime internally. and it does update the img_foreground structure but after the allocation, the memory address data inside _fgmask fail to change since the headers are passed by value.

  - you can seemlingly fix this(but still incurs creation cost) by doing `cv::Mat& img_foreground = _fgmask.getMatRef();`
- and that is because CV_8U is not the same as CV_8UC3 and therefore the check @ Mat::create() in mat.hpp always end up allocating a new array due to type difference

opinion

i think...maybe use Mat instead?

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace cv;

class FrameDifferenceBGS
{
public:
    Mat prev;
    Mat diff;
    bool enableThreshold;
    bool showOutput;
    bool firstTime;
    uchar threshold;
    FrameDifferenceBGS():firstTime(false),enableThreshold(false),showOutput(false),threshold(0)
    {

    }
    void FrameDifferenceBGS::operator()(cv::Mat& _in, cv::Mat &_fg, double _lr)
    {
        if(_in.empty())
            return;

        if(prev.empty())
        {
            prev=_in.clone();
            _fg=cv::Mat::zeros(_in.size(),CV_8UC1);
            return;
        }

        cv::absdiff(prev, _in, diff);

        if(diff.channels() == 3)
            cv::cvtColor(diff, _fg, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        else
            _fg=diff;

        if(enableThreshold)
            cv::threshold(_fg, _fg, threshold, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

        if(showOutput)
            cv::imshow("Frame Difference", _fg);

        prev=_in.clone();
        firstTime = false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    FrameDifferenceBGS bgs;
    Mat frame,fg;
    for(;;)
    {
        cap >> frame; 
        bgs(frame,fg,0);

        imshow("frame", frame);
        imshow("fg", fg);
        if(waitKey(1) ==27) exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### edit 2(modified original)

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

class FrameDifferenceBGS
{
public:
    cv::Mat img_input_prev;
    cv::Mat diff;

    cv::Mat img_foreground;//put this in class in stead of inside the function
    bool enableThreshold;
    bool showOutput;
    bool firstTime;
    uchar threshold;
    FrameDifferenceBGS():firstTime(false),enableThreshold(false),showOutput(false),threshold(0)
    {

    }
    void FrameDifferenceBGS::operator()(cv::InputArray _image, cv::OutputArray _fgmask, double learningRate)
    {
        cv::Mat img_input = _image.getMat();

        if(img_input.empty())
            return;
        if(_fgmask.empty())
            _fgmask.create(img_input.size(), CV_8UC1);
        if(img_input_prev.empty())
        {
            img_input.copyTo(img_input_prev);
            return;
        }

        cv::absdiff(img_input_prev, img_input, img_foreground);

        if(img_foreground.channels() == 3)
            cv::cvtColor(img_foreground, _fgmask, CV_BGR2GRAY);

        if(enableThreshold)
            cv::threshold(img_foreground, img_foreground, threshold, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

        if(showOutput)
            cv::imshow("Frame Difference", img_foreground);

        img_input.copyTo(img_input_prev);
        //img_foreground.copyTo(_fgmask);
        firstTime = false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
    FrameDifferenceBGS bgs;
    cv::Mat frame,fg;
    for(;;)
    {
        cap >> frame; 
        bgs(frame,fg,0);

        cv::imshow("frame", frame);
        cv::imshow("fg", fg);
        if(cv::waitKey(1) ==27) exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to submit a patch to OpenCV, but instead just trying to adapt a library with loads of subtraction algorithms to work the same way as OpenCV's. That method signature doesn't work when you call `BackgroundSubtractor.operator()`. I've tried what you suggested (by passing `_in.type()`) but by the time it converts the colour to B/W it must copy it again, because on the other side I get a coloured image.

Comment: the reason is exactly the same as why new allocation occurs in absdiff. cvtcolor dst type is 8UC1, and the given type is 8UC3 so opencv allocates new memory. and as in the absdiff case _fgmask wasnt updated. you can avoid the copy statement by `cv::cvtColor(img_foreground, _fgmask, CV_BGR2GRAY);` but it's not more efficient since allocation/copying occurs anyway. i have edited the answer with a complete program sticking to the original structure and reusing as much as possible(or i can figure out)

Comment: i was only trying to answer why it doesnt work, not what's the most memory efficient way to do it(probably doenst need to care since this is not very likely to be the biggest bottleneck). using mat help you forget about this since it seems a bit more automatic.in anycase, the updated programs should do fewer allocations per cycles.

Comment: @ZawLin, absDiff doesn't work with BGR Mat images and only work on grayscale images right? This is because, when I absDiff the colour images, all that returned is a blank image, while if I grayscale it first them absDiff, I can see a difference, however there is lots of information loss.

Comment: @ZawLin, this is because, you put absdiff first before converting to grayscale, and you are not the only one. When I do it that way, a blank image if given to me even if I wave in from of the camera, however, if i grayscale it first, no such problem occurs, hence just wish to double confirm(:

Comment: hi, absdiff works with bgr images, you can test `Mat im1 = imread("frame_0000.jpg");Mat im2 = imread("frame_0003.jpg");Mat res;absdiff(im1,im2,res);imshow("gray",res);waitKey(0);` you can see an image. I think it's some other problem you are facing. but you will need to combine the 3 channel differences into a single channel motion data to do more useful stuff. of course you can use other color space models or use channel weights different from grayscale